# in ($\mathbb{R},d_2$), $\mathbb{Q}^{o}=\emptyset$ but $C((\mathbb{Q})^{o})=\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Show that in ($\mathbb{R},d_2$), $\mathbb{Q}^{o}=\emptyset$ but $C((\mathbb{Q})^{o})=\mathbb{R}$.
>   (C(A) meaning the closure of A, not sure how to do a macron in LaTeX).

My attempt: Since for any subset $S$ of a metric space $X$, $S^o=S/\partial S$, I want to show $\partial\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{R}$ and thus have that $\mathbb{Q}^{o}=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{R}=\emptyset$.
$\partial\mathbb{Q}=${all $x\in\mathbb{R}|dist(x,\mathbb{Q}=\inf_{y\in\mathbb{Q}}d(x,y)$}. But $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ so $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$, $d(x,\mathbb{Q})=0=\inf_{y\in\mathbb{Q}}d(x,y)\implies\partial\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{R}$.

To show that $(C(\mathbb{Q})^{o})=\mathbb{R}$, I use the fact that for any set $S\subseteq X$ dense in $X$, $C(S)=X$. Thus we have $\mathbb{R}^o=\mathbb{R}$ since $X^o=X$ in $(X,d)$.

Comment: What is $d_2{}$?

Comment: the usual metric in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Maybe it's fitting into [this family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm) of norms.

Comment: In the last sentence, you need to say "$\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, thus we have $C(\Bbb Q)=\Bbb R$. So  $[C(\Bbb Q)]^\circ=[\Bbb R]^\circ=\Bbb R$".

Comment: In the first line, it looks like the parentheses are in the wrong place.  Also, you can get the closure symbol with either `\bar{A}` (which puts a fixed-width bar over a single letter) or `\overline{A}` (which puts a variable-width bar over an arbitrary expression).

Comment: @Emir Your first line is saying that the closure of $\mathbb{Q}^{\circ}$ is $\mathbb{R}$. I think there is a typo here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are doing for your first argument.

Here, you wish to show that every real number $x$ is a boundary point of $\Bbb Q$.
But $x$ is a boundary point of $\Bbb Q$ if and only if every open set containing $x$ contains  points of $\Bbb Q$ and points of $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$.  But this latter statement is true for any $x$ because both  $\Bbb Q$ and its complement are dense in $\Bbb R$. So, the boundary of $\Bbb Q$ is $\Bbb R$; whence $\Bbb Q^\circ=\emptyset$.

You could also argue more directly that $\Bbb Q^\circ=\emptyset$, by showing that $\Bbb Q$ contains no nonempty open set (every nonempty open set contains irrationals); thus,   the interior of $\Bbb Q$ is empty  (since a point $x$ is an interior point of $A$ if and only if there is an open set $O\subset A$ containing $x$).

For the last part, it seems you're on track; but, it's poorly phrased.
Say something like " $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$; thus $C(\Bbb Q)=\Bbb R$.  Thus
$[C(\Bbb Q)]^\circ=[\Bbb R]^\circ=\Bbb R$".